# IndentationError: unexpected indent in databricks and pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


ghj=finalDF.withColumn("temp", explode(split(regexp_replace(to_json(struct(col("sum(P0)"), col("sum(P1)"), col("sum(P2)"), col("sum(P3)"), col("sum(P4)"), col("sum(P5)"))),"""[\{"\}]""",""), ",")))
           .withColumn("Priority", split(col("temp"),":")[0])
           .withColumn("Count", split(col("temp"),":")[1]).select(col("NAME"), col("SHORT_DESCRIPTION"), col("Priority"), col("Count")).show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot simply continue a Python statement to the next line. You need a `\` at the end of each line that has a continuation:

```
ghj=finalDF.withColumn(.....)\
   .withColumn(.....)\
   .withColumn(.....).show()
```

Make sure there are no other symbols (even spaces) after the `\`.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the `\` suggestion, you can also use parentheses (note, no commas):

```py
ghj = (
   finalDF.withColumn(.....)
   .withColumn(.....)
   .withColumn(.....)
   .show()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `\` to move data to new line

```
ghj = finalDF.withColumn("temp", explode(split(regexp_replace(to_json(struct(col("sum(P0)"), col("sum(P1)"), col("sum(P2)"), col("sum(P3)"), col("sum(P4)"), col("sum(P5)"))),"""[\{"\}]""",""), ",")))\
           .withColumn("Priority", split(col("temp"),":")[0])\
           .withColumn("Count", split(col("temp"),":")[1]).select(col("NAME"), col("SHORT_DESCRIPTION"), col("Priority"), col("Count")).show()
```